# JDBC program that connects with MS Server stored in different computer

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

This is my code that connects to MS server stored in different server.It gives an error called Class not found exception.I have added sqljdbc4.jar and sqlserver.jar. Please provide me the solution for the same.

```
<html>
<head>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.*;"

 %>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%java.sql.Connection con;
java.sql.Statement s;
java.sql.ResultSet rs;
java.sql.PreparedStatement pst;
String username=request.getParameter("username");
String Password=request.getParameter("password");
final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
final String DB_URL = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://10.5.5.205:0;databaseName=JavaUsecase";
final String USER = "sqljob";
final String PASS = "sqljob";
con = null;
s = null;
try{

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");


  // System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
   con =java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
   //System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

   //STEP 4: Execute a query
   //System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
   s = con.createStatement();

   String sql = "INSERT INTO account " +
                "VALUES ("+username+","+Password+")";
   s.executeUpdate(sql);
}
catch(Exception se){
    //Handle errors for JDBC
    se.printStackTrace();
 }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

The error i got is:-

```
2015-05-18 15:22:47.159:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
2015-05-18 15:22:49.394:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:187)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at org.apache.jsp.Logdatabse_jsp._jspService(Logdatabse_jsp.java:71)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Post your stack trace and/or the exact error you are getting.  This will massively cut down on our debugging time.

Comment: Please edit your post and include the entire stack trace, and also identify the line in your code that throws the exception.

Comment: I answer your question but I need to know your exception stack trace to answer your question in better way, you can find this information in your application server log files, also you dont provide which kind of application server you use

Comment: @Tim - just edited the post..please have a look at it..

Comment: How are you building your code?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have the sqljdbc4.jar and sqlserver.jar under WebApps\yourProject\WEB-INF\lib folder. thats if you use Tomcat, otherway to do that is to add jars in TOMCAT_HOME\lib folder.